# Page view controller with 3 view controller pages

Tags: ios, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

I am new to iPad development. I know how to use images for Page view controller. My problem is i have 3 charts which i have done in three view controllers.. How can i combine all the view controllers in a single page view controller. I have for now kept three view controllers.

I have tried lot of tutorials but none explains me how to use three view controllers
I have done like this now but this is wrong

```
-(IBAction)handleSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)sender {

    LastLearningSessionViewController *last=[[LastLearningSessionViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentViewController:last animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: you will have to to create a page view controller and add three *container view controllers* to it, in each container you can then embed the appropriate chart view controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see it appears you may have done this slightly wrong.

First you need to create a controller for the `UIPageViewController`, that is a datasource and delegate.

**Please note all code has been written directly to the answer and has not been tested.**

`MyUIPageViewController.h`

```
@interface
MyUIPageViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate>
{
  NSNumber *currentIndex //Using NSNumber to handle 32bit/64bit easier.
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPageViewController *pageViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *controllersArray //Used to help navigate between controllers
@end
```

`MyUIPageViewController.m`

```
#import MyUIPageViewController.h

@implementation MyUIPageViewController

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName
                     bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
{
  if(self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle])
  {
     //Create ChartViewController1 (UIViewController *ChartViewController1 = [[ChartViewController1Class alloc] init];)
     //Create ChartViewController2
     //Create ChartViewController3

     //Now we have created all 3 chartViewControllers, create our controllers Array with the controller objects.         

     self.controllersArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:ChartViewController1, ChartViewController2, ChartViewController3];

     //Currently setting to 0. A proper way of handling with Multi-tasking is to store the index value from before, but not dealing with that right now.
     currentIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];

     //Create our PageViewController. Currently set to PageCurl and all pages will go from left to right.
     //These options can be changed, if so desired (Scroll Effect like iBooks Textbooks and a page change from bottom to top like a flip book.

     self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    //Set ourselves as the datasource and delegate to handle the pages etc.

    self.pageViewController.datasource = self;
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self;

    //We need to set the viewControllers for the PageViewController, because this is the initial load, we will not animate the change.

    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:self.controllersArray direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:^ (BOOL finished) {
    //No animation is being done so no need to worry.
}];

     //Set our view to be the pagecontroller's view, so we can see it all.
     self.view = self.pageViewController.view;
  }

 return self;
}

//DataSource Methods:

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
  viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
   //As this method looks for the previous view controller. If our current index is 0, there is no previous VC. But using the objectAtIndex method on the array would throw a outOfRange exception

   if([self.currentIndex intValue] <= 0)
   {
     return nil;
   }
   else
   {
     return [self.controllersArray objectAtIndex:([self.currentIndex intValue] - 1)];
   }
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
   viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
   //As this method looks for the next view controller. If our current index is the maximum value the array count and be (2), there isn't a new VC to push. But using the objectAtIndex method on the array would throw a outOfRange exception

   if([self.currentIndex intValue] >= self.controllersArray.count)
   {
     return nil;
   }
   else
   {
     return [self.controllersArray objectAtIndex:([self.currentIndex intValue] + 1)];
   }
}

//Delegate Methods

- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
{
   if(transitionCompleted)
   {
     //We will update our currentIndex, only if the transition has happened.

     switch (previousViewControllers)
     {
       case 0:
       //Something went wrong :S
       break;
       case 1:
       //We are either in Vertical Orientation of the first viewController is only being shown.
       if([pageViewController.viewControllers contains:[self.controllersArray objectAtIndex:([currentIndex intValue]+ 1)]])
       {
         currentIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([currentIndex intValue] + 1)];
       }
       else
       {
         if([currentIndex intValue] == 0)
         {
           //Saftey Net.
         }
         else
         {
         currentIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([currentIndex intValue] - 1)];
         }
       }
       break;
       case 2:

       //We are in horizontal Orientation.

       //With 3 View Controllers the only ViewController that will be in both arrays is the ViewController at index 1. We just need to see if the pageViewControllers viewcontrollers array contains the ViewController at index 0 or index 1.
       if([pageViewController.viewControllers contains:[self.controllersArray objectAtIndex:([currentIndex intValue]+ 1)]])
       {
         currentIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([currentIndex intValue] + 1)];
       }
       else
       {

         if([currentIndex intValue] == 0)
         {
           //Saftey Net.
         }
         else
         {
         currentIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([currentIndex intValue] - 1)];
         }

       }

       break;
       default:
       //Should never reach here.
       break;
     }
   }
}
@end
```

It is also handy to look at the reference documentation:

[Class Reference - Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html)